# What file extension should I use for dynamic RSS

Tags: php, .htaccess, rss

I am currently developing a dynamic RSS feed that will automatically pull articles from a MySQL database. The code is below

```
<?php 

//Include the post retreival script
require_once '../phpScripts/rss_db_setup.php';

//Set the content type
header('Content-type: text/xml');

//Set up the RSS feed information
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>'.
 '<rss version="2.0">'.

 '<channel>'.
 '<title>Company Name</title>'.
 '<link>http://www.company.ca</link>'.
 '<description></description>'.
 '<category></category>';

//Retreive posts from the database
$rssData = new rssData();
echo $rssData->generateFeed($dbcon);

//Close the feed
echo '</channel></rss>';

?>
```

I am wondering whether this file should be saved as a .xml or a .php? I have added the following line to my .htaccess file, but do not really understand exactly how it works

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

Is this a correct way to do this? Or should I use another htaccess function such as modRewrite, or use a CRON job to generate a new .xml every day or so?

Comment: all file names are meaningless, it's headers and content that counts

Comment: `.dynamicrssrenderedviaphp`. I kid of course. +1 to @Dagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml` line, Apache will be able to serve XML files containing some PHP code inside. So you can save this file as a .xml, the PHP code will be interpreted

Perhaps you should add a cache manager in order to avoid generating the same feed when there is no new article?

Comment: Perfect! exactly what i wanted to know, not sure how to add a cache manager, but will look into it

Answer (score 8):

RSS doesn't need a extension. It doesn't care if the url is `/feed.php` `/feed.xml` or even just `/feed/`. It's not like the files on your own harddrive. HTTP send the content-type header to specify what kind of file it is.

It however (officially) needs the correct content-type header. You specify text/xml in your code, which should officially be application/rss+xml.

Using AddType could be a problem if you use static xml files elsewhere on the server. PHP would choke on the  part at the beginning of every xml file, give a nice error message resulting in invalid xml.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Wasnt sure if RSS Readers would encounter errors. Not using XML elsewhere, but probably a good idea anyhow for future purposes

Comment: You could just put the file in a folder named 'feeds' or something and put the htaccess and xml file in there. That way the htaccess only affects that folder and not the rest. I also checked my own feedlist; roughly 40% has no extension, 40% has xml extension, rest uses .rss or .php, some even with a querystring.